# Python: catch Exception or keyboard interrupt

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I have the following code:

```
import time

try:
    time.sleep(3)
    raise Exception('error')
except Exception or KeyboardInterrupt:
    print(">>> Error or keyboard interrupt")
```

I want to catch either error or key board interrupt. But currently, it catches only Exception, keyboard interrupt is not handled.

- If I remove Exception and leave only Keyboard interrupt, it catches only keyboard interrupt.
- If I remove KeyboardInterrupt and leave only Exception, it catches only Exception.

**Is there a way to catch both ?**

Comment: You can use `tuple` of exceptions. `except (Exception, KeyboardInterrupt):`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to handle the two cases differently the best way of doing this is to have multiple `except` blocks:

```py
import time

try:
    time.sleep(3)
    raise Exception('error')

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Keyboard interrupt")

except Exception as e:
    print("Exception encountered:", e)
```

Mind the order!

Answer (score 3):

According to https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions
you can use

```py
except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError):
```

```
import time

try:
    time.sleep(3)
    raise Exception('error')
except (Exception, KeyboardInterrupt):
    print(">>> Error or keyboard interrupt")
```